# How to post message to facebook wall from android fb sdk

Tags: android, facebook

Hi everyone
I found this is working.

```
                    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                    parameters.putString("message", "This is a test message.");
                    mFacebook.request("me/feed", parameters, "POST");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is full code.

```
Facebook mFacebook = new Facebook(FACEBOOK_APP_ID);
SessionStore.restore(mFacebook, mContext);

try {
    TextView post_edit = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.post_edit);
    String message = String.valueOf(post_edit.getText());
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("message", message);
    mFacebook.request("me/feed", parameters, "POST");
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

Comment: How long does it take this message to apprear on wall

Comment: Immediately after it finished

Comment: Does this code still work? not working for me.  basically the message parameter does nothing :(.